# TypeError: Cannot read property 'original_title' of undefined

Tags: json, angularjs

Users on my website can search for a movietitle and then a dropdown list will show all corresponding titles. Then they can click on a title to add that movie to their watchlist.

When they click on a title the `addMovie` function below triggers.

```
  $scope.addMovie = function() {

    'http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/206647?api_key=a8f7039633f2065942cd8a28d7cadad4&append_to_response=releases'
    // Search for release dates using the ID.
    var base = 'http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/';
    var movieID = $(event.currentTarget).parent().find('.movieID').text()
    var apiKey = 'a8f7039633f2065942cd8a28d7cadad4&query='
    var append_to_response = '&append_to_response=releases'
    var callback = 'JSON_CALLBACK'; // provided by angular.js
    var url = base + movieID + '?api_key=' + apiKey + append_to_response + '&callback=' + callback;

    $http.jsonp(url,{ cache: true}).
      success(function (data, status, headers, config) {

        if (status == 200) {
          // $scope.movieListID = data.results;
          $scope.movieListID = data;
          console.log($scope.movieListID)
        } else {
          console.error('Error happened while getting the movie list.')
        }

      }).
      error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        console.error('Error happened while getting the movie list.')
      });

    createMovie.create({
            title: $scope.movieListID.original_title
    }).then(init);

  };
```

The http request works and in the console I can find the object and the `original_title` but the create method fails.

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'original_title' of undefined
    at Scope.$scope.addMovie`

So I'm guessing `title: $scope.movieListID.original_title` isn't the correct way to save the JSON data directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this way.

```
success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

        if (status == 200) {
            // $scope.movieListID = data.results;
            $scope.movieListID = data;
            console.log($scope.movieListID);

            createMovie.create({ title: $scope.movieListID.original_title }).then(init);




        } else {
            console.error('Error happened while getting the movie list.')
        }

    })
```

you calling `createMovie.create` outside `http.jsonp` 
which is Asynchronous call.Either you call it inside `http` call or chain it using promise.
.

Comment: Thanks, I thought that `MovieListID` was accesable to everything in that controller.

Answer (score 0):

Please assign empty object to $scope.movieListID before making $http request and check once. It may be causing issue due to hoisting. I am unable to check as there is no fiddle or Pen.

$scope.movieListID = {};